# Static class method returns object when called outside of classes, but returns empty object when called inside of different classes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm experiencing this really strange PHP behavior and I'm at a bit of a loss.

The rundown: I've got Doctrine ORM setup with my own abstraction class to make it a bit easier to interact with Entities, while having the benefits of Doctrine. I know I need to add dependency injection but this is a start.

I've got Entity ORM calls working great with the tests I've made from a controller script, which is a plain file outside of any class.

Once I try to do any Entity ORM calls inside of any other class, it returns an empty object. I traced things down to a static method that builds the EntityManager for Doctrine. It's really weird; *inside* of the static method I can trace the object I'm creating/returning and it's fine. When I actually call the static method though, the returned value is an empty object. Here's a simplified structure:

```
namespace MyApp\Core;

use MyApp\Core\System;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class SystemDBA {

public static function entityManager()
{
    $paths = array(PLATFORM_ROOT."/classes/entities");
    $isDevMode = false;

    $db_settings = System::getSystemSettings();

    $dbParams = array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user'     => $db_settings['username'],
        'password' => $db_settings['password'],
        'dbname'   => $db_settings['database'],
    );

    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);

    $em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

    // this will always return the right kind of EntityManager object no matter where an entity is called from.
    error_log(json_encode($em));

    // this however is sending back an empty object when an entity is called inside of a class. 
    return $em;
}
```

The `$em` return vs error_log is where the problem is above. No matter where the system gets called from error_log is always correct, but the return is not. Here's the rest of the chain:

```
namespace MyApp\Entities;

use MyApp\Core\System;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use MyApp\Core\SystemDBA;

class EntityBase
{

    public static function find($id)
    {
        $db = SystemDBA::entityManager();
        // if it's an array of ids we can try to get multiples
        $object = $db->getRepository(get_called_class())->findOneBy(['id'=>$id]);

        if ($object) return $object;

        return false;
    }
```

The first line of the method `find()` is where `$db` is an empty object instead of a Doctrine EntityManager object like I'm expecting.

**EDIT** I've confirmed that `get_called_class()` is returning `MyApp\\Entities\\People` in EntityBase regardless of whether I call the entity from another class, or from a standalone PHP file. So it doesn't seem to be an issue of repository class name.

```
namespace MyApp\Entities;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="people")
 */

class People extends EntityBase {
```

Simple ORM Entity class that extends `EntityBase`

So finally, if I call an Entity from a standalone controller like this:

```
namespace MyApp\Controllers;
use MyApp\Entities\People;

$user = People::find(123);
```

It works fine, `SystemDBA::entityManager()` both externally returns and also internally traces the right object.

However if I try to run this from inside of another class, `SystemDBA::entityManager()` internally traces the right object but externally returns an empty object.

```
namespace MyApp\SomeStuff;

use MyApp\Entities\People;

class myClass {
    protected function getUser($user_id) {
        $user = People::find(123);
        }
```

I was initially thinking this was related to Doctrine but it seems to be some sort of issue with PHP at large. I tried changing the class method in last example to not be protected, but doesn't seem to have any bearing. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

> Gets the name of the class the static method is called in.

And you call static method inside `myClass`, so it cannot work.

By the way, I would not recommend going that way, after some time you will truly regret using statics, introducing dependencies like this. 
And you create new `EntityManager` instance on every call (so a new connection), that is inefficient and will break doctrine behaviour (you can read about unit of work).

Dependency injection with container is the proper way.

Comment: You're 100% correct, I should be using dependency injection

Comment: You know, as far as the class name lookup goes, I did try error logging that thinking it might be the issue, but I always got the same Entity class name regardless of where it was called from. I'll try the dependency injection and this and go from there.

Comment: I've confirmed just now that `get_called_class()` is returning `MyApp\\Entities\\People` in EntityBase regardless of whether I call it from another class or from a standalone PHP file. So that doesn't seem to be the direct problem here. Adding this point as an edit.